# ur_robot_driver: this controller requires a scaled_controllers::ScaledPositionJointInterface

Tags: ros, universal-robots

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
roslaunch ur_robot_driver ur3e_bringup.launch robot_ip:=XXX limited:=true kinematics_config:="${HOME}/my_robot_calibration.yaml"
```

When I ran the above, I got the following error: I can't solve this.

```
[ERROR] [1633410437.724233056]: This controller requires a hardware interface of type 'scaled_controllers::ScaledPositionJointInterface'. Make sure this is registered in the hardware_interface::RobotHW class.
[ERROR] [1633410437.724256060]: Initializing controller 'scaled_pos_joint_traj_controller' failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/387939/ur_robot_driver:-this-controller-requires-a-scaled_controllers::scaledpositionjointinterface/) by [aip](https://answers.ros.org/users/77750/aip/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2021-10-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-10-05**:
I would suggest to post this as an issue on the tracker of [UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver](https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver). The scaled controllers have been supported since the first release of that driver, so something must be wrong there.

If you do post there, please include much more information (such as your workspace layout, how you installed everything, the complete `roslaunch` output, etc).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-10-05**:
And when you post on the issue tracker, post a comment here with a link to your issue, so we keep things connected.

**Comment by [aip](https://answers.ros.org/users/77750/aip/) on 2021-10-05**:
https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver/issues/479

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-10-05**:
Thanks for posting the issue, but you did not add more information.

Please add the full `roslaunch` output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver/issues/480

---

Originally posted by [aip](https://answers.ros.org/users/77750/aip/) with karma: 16 on 2021-10-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-10-06**:
Could you please summarise the solution here in your answer?

**Comment by [aip](https://answers.ros.org/users/77750/aip/) on 2021-10-06**:
I installed the scaled controller in my workspace and it worked. It used to work, so I don't know why this happened.